# Can Notepad++ mark scrollbar with visual indicators of search results?

Tags: notepad++

Can Notepad++ highlight search results in its scrollbar area, whereby the scrollbar represents the height of the entire document being viewed and is visually marked (colour-coded, ticked or otherwise) relative to where the results occur in the actual document?

Does an option or plugin exist for this?

Some other software programs like Eclipse and Google Chrome implement this kind of high level scrollbar visualization to aid understanding of results in one view.

I found the following example image on the Internet to demonstrate the concept - it's not Notepad++ but shows the scrollbar concept being referred to.

[image: Example of highlighted scrollbar]

Answer (score 28):

There is a plugin for that, it's called "SmartHighlighter" and is part of the [jN Plugin suite](https://github.com/sieukrem/jn-npp-plugin).

Comment: Looks like the site has changed and the old listing of plugins doesn't exist anymore. Had to use the Wayback Machine to find it: https://web.archive.org/web/20140213023146/http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Central#S

Comment: To get only the Smart Highlighter and not the other plugins, in the `jN\includes` folder, move all of the scripts except `SmartHighlighter.js` and `MenuCmds.js` into `disabled`.

Comment: to test it I just had to select a text (no need to run the search). I though it did not work because I did not saw the highlights. I needed to change the color to see them: setting/style configurator. In language:global style // in style: smart highlighting set the background color. downloaded here: https://web.archive.org/web/20131209225342/http://code.google.com/p/jn-npp-plugin/downloads/detail?name=jN_1.0.34.zip&can=2&q=

Comment: Plugin works fine for now (npp 7.5.1), and I want to add one detail to @Arithmomaniac comment: if you want Smart Highlighter settings to work, you will also need `Dialog.js` file.

Comment: URL for install complete plugin: https://github.com/sieukrem/jn-npp-plugin/wiki/How-to-start

Answer (score 0):

There's a feature that puts a line marker next to the line numbers.

Search > find. Check the option "mark line".

Comment: That's nice but doesn't provide the same high level visual of the entire document at once. Thank you for posting this close second - I might have to be satisfied with it.

Comment: You should note that it is a separate search mode, not merely a "feature".

Comment: It does if you also open "Document Map" (view -> Document map) it does exactly what OP wants!

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you how reliant I have become on Chrome and VS smart-scrollbar.  I'm starting to greatly dislike apps that don't have this feature.  When I try to enhance Notepad++ it seems to have startup issues.

In doing a search for text editors with this capability I started thinking how I wish there was an editor like the visual studio editor and then discovered something Microsoft released in Nov 2015 called **Visual Studio Code**.

It's free and I'm wondering now why I hadn't started using it sooner.

Here's the URL:  https://code.visualstudio.com

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question of how to enable this feature in Notepad++, but rather seems to just encourage using another application altogether.