# Notepad++: Scroll Bar Colour

Tags: mouse, notepad++, scrolling

N++ 7.1, W10 (Home 1607): 
Is there some way of modifying the scroll bar colour or style as the outline of the scrollbar slider is barely distinguishable making it non-locatable for any mouse selection. 
The [Smart Highlighter](https://superuser.com/questions/216088/can-notepad-mark-scrollbar-with-visual-indicators-of-search-results) does not touch the style, there is no information on the default Scintilla setting for scroll style at the [wiki](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Scrolling) and scroll bars don't appear in config.xml or any of the N++ themes. 
Any method of changing the appearance of either the right or bottom scroll bars?

Comment: this might work as a nice substitute ... no clicking required. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380636/rockscroll-like-plugin-for-notepad